# Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.fonts

Tags: flutter, dart

I am doing an exercise, where I have to open an URL with the onTap() function, the URL is a YouTube link, when I tap the button, the screen of my emulated phone goes black and my debugger displays this for a couple seconds: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.fonts

Then it goes back to whatever it was doing, shows it again, and so forth, until it detects a crash and exits the app. Any ideas? I found similar stuff, but I think the last part is most important, since it's different from the ones that have been asked

I tapped the button that launched the link, expected to see a video, but just got a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to launch youtube videos on youtube app

After you install the package to your project enter the line below inside the `onTap(){}` of your button.

```
launchUrlString('youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$videoID');
```